# How does `=<<` work in Scalaz.Kleisli

Tags: scala, scalaz

For the following example for Kleisli function composition from the Scalaz repo:

```
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._
  import Kleisli._

  import scala.util._

  case class Continent(name: String, countries: List[Country] = List.empty)
  case class Country(name: String, cities: List[City] = List.empty)
  case class City(name: String, isCapital: Boolean = false, inhabitants: Int = 20)

  val data: List[Continent] = List(
    Continent("Europe"),
    Continent("America",
      List(
        Country("USA",
          List(
            City("Washington"), City("New York"))))),
    Continent("Asia",
      List(
        Country("India",
          List(City("New Dehli"), City("Calcutta"))))))

  def continents(name: String): List[Continent] =
    data.filter(k => k.name.contains(name))

  def countries(continent: Continent): List[Country] = continent.countries

  def cities(country: Country): List[City] = country.cities

  def inhabitants(c: City): Int = c.inhabitants
  val allCities = kleisli(continents) >==> countries >==> cities
```

I get the following results:

```
// fine, expected result for "America"
scala> (allCities =<< List("America")).map(println)
City(Washington,false,20)
City(New York,false,20)
res16: List[Unit] = List((), ())

// confused, why does this bring back the same cities for "Amer"
scala> (allCities =<< List("Amer")).map(println)
City(Washington,false,20)
City(New York,false,20)
res17: List[Unit] = List((), ())

// confused again, has brought back cities for America and Asia - seems to be matching on the first character??
scala> (allCities =<< List("A")).map(println)
City(Washington,false,20)
City(New York,false,20)
City(New Dehli,false,20)
City(Calcutta,false,20)

// confused again, brings back everything:

scala> (allCities =<< List("")).map(println)
City(Washington,false,20)
City(New York,false,20)
City(New Dehli,false,20)
City(Calcutta,false,20)
res19: List[Unit] = List((), (), (), ())
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your expectations? `continents` returns all of the continents that contain the given `name` string (in any position), so the results seem on target to me.

Comment: If we take the second example,why does it bring back the cities for America? Why/how does it match on "Amer"? I would expect it to match on the full string America but not  "Amer"

Comment: It's the `.filter(k => k.name.contains(name))` part.

Comment: Doh! Overlooked it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: the `Kleisli` parts aren't really relevant here—the behavior you're seeing is entirely the result of the `filter` in the `continents` method. It returns all continents with names that contain the argument to the method, which means that both `America` and `Asia` are returned for `"A"`, everything is returned for `""`, etc.